Getting a list of windows paths for all open windows explorer.exe browsers?
I'd like to open a bunch of explorer.exe browsers and would like to run some python to get a list of the paths that are currently open in those browsers.
I have tried using psutil but it only gives me information on the parent process and I wasn't sure how to even get the details of the browser that's open.

You can enumerate all of the top-level windows using pywinauto or win32gui.EnumWindows, fetching only the window that match the Explorer window class, then pull the title.  That won't get windows with multiple tabs.
